# Get object type from Entity Framework ObjectStateEntry

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

Within my overriding function for Entity Frameworks SaveChanges() function I am attempting to serialize the original entity and the modified entity, however I am having a hard time trying to deduce what the object type is so that I can pass it as a parameter to the XmlSerializer object.

```
Public Overrides Function SaveChanges() As Integer
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()

    Dim ctx As ObjectContext = DirectCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
    Dim objectStateEntryList As List(Of ObjectStateEntry) = ctx.ObjectStateManager.
        GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added Or EntityState.Modified Or EntityState.Deleted).ToList()

    For Each Entry As ObjectStateEntry In objectStateEntryList
        If Not Entry.IsRelationship Then
            Dim objectType As String = Entry.Entity.GetType.Name.Split("_").First
            Select Case Entry.State
                Case EntityState.Modified
                    For Each propertyName As String In Entry.GetModifiedProperties()
                        Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(Entry.Entity.GetType)
                        Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter
                        ser.Serialize(sw, Entry.OriginalValues)
                        Dim serializedObject As String = sw.ToString
                    Next
            End Select

        End If
    Next

    Return MyBase.SaveChanges()
End Function
```

I attempted the above, but to not avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim originalType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(Entry.Entity.GetType())
```

[GetObjectType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.getobjecttype(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static method.

Then just convert entity object to new type

```
Dim convertedEntity = Convert.ChangeType(Entry.Entity, originalType)
```

[Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) is also static, stored in System.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. As an extension of that, how would I get the original object and the new object in a format that I can serialize?

Comment: I get "Object must implement IConvertible."

Comment: @JacobMason What is the definite type of entities that don't implement IConvertible? I had the same issue and it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow the question.